# php form check if data exists before sending the action

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form which send data to another page. I want to check if the data exists in the directory, and then redirect, otherwise show an error.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="<?php checkMyFile(); ?>">
    <select class="form-control" style="width:auto;" name="mydata">
        <option value="id1">1</option>
        <option value="id2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I have the following php function at the top of my above html form:

```
<?php
funtion checkFile (){

    if(!isset($_POST['mydata']) or !file_exists('../data/'.basename($_POST['mydata']).'.txt')){
      echo  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';

    } else {

        return "my/destination/page.php"
    }

}

?>
```

but currently it is showing white page with no errors. 
What is the reason that it is not working? what is the solution?

Comment: Errrr, it does not work that way. You cannot run a PHP function from an `action`. You have to run the script file (xxx.php), pass a parameter in the POSTED data which will be tested by the newly instantiated `xxx.php` script and if set the PHP code will call the function

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you please suggest an answer to this ? with your explanations. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets assume this code is all in a file called `xxx.php`

First all you can do in an action is tell the browser which script to send the forms inputs to, you cannot specify a specific function within that script.

```
<?php
// while testing, always make sure error reporting is on
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$errormsg = '';

// corrected spelling error of funtion
function checkFile (){

    if(!isset($_POST['mydata']) or !file_exists('../data/'.basename($_POST['mydata']).'.txt')){
        return '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                        Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later
                     </div>';

    } else {

        header("Location: my/destination/page.php");
        // exit a you are now sending a new page and this one is irrelevant
        exit;
    }

}

// was the form submitted, or is this just the page being initially loaded
// NOTE: I gave the submit button a `name` attribute of `submit`
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $errormsg = checkFile();
}    
?>
<-- Usual doctype/html/head/body tags ommitted for brevity -->

<?php  
    // output the error message somewhere sensible on your page
    // which may not actually be here
    if ($errormsg != '' ) {
        echo $errormsg;
    }
?>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="xxx.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select class="form-control" style="width:auto;" name="mydata">
        <option value="id1">1</option>
        <option value="id2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it is not working. even if the data exists, i get the error message

Comment: Are you sure about the need for the 2 dots in `../data/'`

Comment: Might this work `!file_exists('data/'.basename($_POST['mydata'])`

Comment: now it works, but i get a console error saying that the file ` www.example.com/data/.txt` doesn't exist. it is not being passed to the destination php file.

Comment: Hmm did I miss something, let me check

Comment: Did you change `xxx.php` to be the Real name of your real PHP script?

Comment: yes i did, it should be the same name as the file that contains the code. it is `index.php`

Comment: All I can think of, is I added a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` tag, does that help?

Comment: no it doesn't help, just a point to share with you, i get the file in the destination php file like this:  `$file = ../data/'.basename($_POST['mydata']).'.txt';`

Comment: so this bit can't get the variable`mydata` which is passed to it from the index.php form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change:

```
return "my/destination/page.php"
```

To:

```
header('Location: my/destination/page.php');
```

or:

```
$url =  sprintf(
    "%s://%s%s",
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  );

header('Location: '.$url.'/my/destination/page.php');
```

Regarding this part:

```
action="<?php checkMyFile(); ?>"
```

change it to the PHP file where your code is located

Example:

```
action="checker.php"
```

and inside **checker.php** is:

```
if(!isset($_POST['mydata']) or !file_exists('../data/'.basename($_POST['mydata']).'.txt')){
      echo  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';

    } else {

    header('Location: my/destination/page.php');
    }
```

Comment: Well yes, but that really does not cover the main issue now does it

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh right I missed that part of his code regarding the action. let me add my suggestion in my answer

Comment: @passion updated the answer and choose which of the header works for you